# A book for advanced field theory

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory

I am searching for an alternative text to chapter 5 of Bourbaki for field theory, that covers, for example, separable and inseparable degrees. I know the basics about field theory and Galois theory. I'd like not a complete book on algebra like Lang.

Comment: Advanced undergraduate or graduate?

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/FieldTheory.pdf

Comment: @Alizter: I don't have preference.

Comment: The link is not working now. There might be an alternative, http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/FieldTheory.pdf